# Facing issue with buttons in a listview in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am getting a list of users from firebase using `StreamBuilder`. I am trying to make an 'Add as a friend' button for the user to make friends with each other. But there is an issue I am facing. The issue here is when I click on any one of the user, all the other add buttons start with the loader. I want the loader to be only for the particular user selected.

This is before I click on anyone:
[image: 1]

This is After I click on any user:
[image: 2]

Here is the code I am currently using:

```
Column(
  children: [
    StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('users')
            .where("uid", isNotEqualTo: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          List<Column> clientWidgets = [];
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const CustomProgressBar();
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(
              child: ErrorMessage(message: snapshot.error.toString()),
            );
          } else if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return const Center(child: Center(child: CustomProgressBar()));
          } else {
            final clients = snapshot.data?.docs.reversed.toList();
            for (var client in clients!) {
              final clientWidget = Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  ListTile(
                    leading: FadedScaleAnimation(
                      child: CircleAvatar(
                          radius: 30.0,
                          backgroundImage: Image.network(client["avatar"] ??
                                  "https://i.pravatar.cc/300")
                              .image),
                    ),
                    trailing: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        print(client['name']);
                        print(isLoading);
                        setState(() {
                          isLoading = true;
                        });
                        PalRequestModel palRequest = PalRequestModel(
                          name: ap.userModel.name,
                          avatar: ap.userModel.avatar,
                          phoneNumber: ap.userModel.phoneNumber,
                          uid: ap.userModel.uid,
                        );
                        ap.sendRequestToPals(
                            context: context,
                            palRequests: palRequest,
                            palId: client["uid"],
                            onSuccess: () {
                              setState(() {
                                isLoading = false;
                              });
                            });
                      },
                      child: Container(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
                              border: Border.all(
                                  width: 0.8, color: Colors.grey)),
                          child: isLoading
                              ? Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                      vertical: 5.0, horizontal: 10.0),
                                  child: Row(
                                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                    mainAxisAlignment:
                                        MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                    children: [
                                      CustomProgressBar(),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                )
                              : Row(
                                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                  children: const [
                                    Icon(
                                      Icons.person_add,
                                      size: 20,
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      width: 5,
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      "add",
                                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                )),
                    ),
                    title: Text(
                      "${client["name"]}".toLowerCase(),
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      style: TextStyles.h2,
                    ),
                    subtitle: Text(
                      "${client["bio"]}".toLowerCase(),
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      style: TextStyles.bodyText,
                    ),
                  ),
                  
                  Divider(
                    height: 0.1,
                    thickness: 0.5,
                    endIndent: 10,
                    indent: 10,
                    color: ApplicationColors.offWhite,
                  ),
                ],
              );
              clientWidgets.add(clientWidget);
            }
          }
          return clientWidgets.isEmpty
              ? Center(
                  child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: 10.0, bottom: 5.0, left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
                  child: Container(
                      height: 50,
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(
                              color: ApplicationColors.primaryColor
                                  .withOpacity(0.5),
                              width: 3),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                      child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                        "no pals yet",
                      ))),
                ))
              : Expanded(child: ListView(children: clientWidgets));
        }),
    
  ],
);
```

Please let me know what I can do about it and where I am going wrong? Thank you!

Comment: create a variable to store client when the users click add update the variable. If the variable client and the client that's being rendered is same then show the loading effect

Answer (score 0):

You're using only one global `isLoading` variable to control the loading animation. So when it's `true`, all of your buttons will be loading at the same time.

The best way to create the loading animation in this situation is creating a `null` variable for the `Client` like:

```dart
dynamic isLoadingClient;
```

The condition of loading animation:

```dart
return isLoadingClient == client ? LoadingAnimation() : YourRealWidget();
```

When you want to show a loading animation of a Button:

```dart
setState(() => isLoadingClient = client);
```

When you want to show the original Widget:

```dart
setState(() => isLoadingClient = null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using is loading for all button, so when you change it, all button react with it, i guess it is better that u  make your button widget separately in other class and put your variable in that class and send your bool through constructor.